# org mode - export shell results with if condition like [[ fails on Unable to resolve link

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to archive a config file in my org document:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /ssh:jetpac@server:  :var CONFIG="efile" :exports 
both :eval query :results output scalar raw
cat /builds/$CONFIG
#+END_SRC


#+RESULTS:
if [[ -z $BUILD ]]; then BUILD=0; fi
```

This works nicely, code gets evaluated, config file brought over into the results block. However, when trying to export, the RESULTS block is being evaluated by org and the '[[' condition tricks it to evaluate it as an invalid ORG link.
Is there a way how to disable this behaviour for the results block? I have spent good deal of time reading docs and googling, no luck so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The +BEGIN_SRC has the ':no-expand' switch, which does exactly what I was looking for and that I have originally overlooked.

The following works:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /ssh:jetpac@server:  :var CONFIG="efile":exports both :results value verbatim code :no-expand
cat /builds/$CONFIG
#+END_SRC


#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
if [[ -z $BUILD ]]; then BUILD=0; fi
#+end_example
```